# How to diagnose App engine module Routing Requests not working?

Tags: google-app-engine

the following dispatch.xml doesn't work for our appengine app (java):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dispatch-entries>
<dispatch>
    <url>*/favicon.ico</url>
    <module>default</module>
</dispatch>
<dispatch>
    <url>*/*</url>
    <module>x-frontend</module>
</dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

Both modules have been uploaded, but nothing hits the x-frontend module.

The code is derived from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

I put the dispatch.xml under appengine-modules-sample-java/root/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. root is the default module I added.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the mvn command says:

```
Skipping dispatch.xml - consider running "appcfg.sh update_dispatch <war-dir>"
```

which means we have to run it manually. mvn plugin doesn't do the job.